# Carrierwave setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

please, could you please have a look to my config? I'm trying to setup carrierwave in my app but it doesn't work in the production server. It's working locally even as production environment. The thing is that it's saving the images into the tmp directory but the result is 'Empty file upload result'. I tried save to file and save to S3, same result. I'm using Passenger - Nginx.

I'm getting mad with this for two days now. Any idea or tip even about how I can debug this is welcome. I setup all permissions so I don't think it's a permissions issue. It could be a cache thing, the files are stored into tmp directory but it seems that the app don't see them as owned by the user???

Thanks!!!

```
#application.rb

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end



# avatar_uploader.rb

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png mp3)
end
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
  end

end



# carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
      :aws_access_key_id      => 'ACCESS',       # required
      :aws_secret_access_key  => 'SECRET',       # required
      :region                 => 'eu-west-1'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
    config.fog_directory  = 'my_app_bucket' 
  end



# production.rb 

MyApp::Application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true # default false, debug true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true #default true
  config.serve_static_assets = true  # Carrierwave true - Default false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false # false for real production
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
  config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

My ImageMagick install was missing delegates. Now:

```
convert -list configure

    DELEGATES     bzlib fontconfig freetype jpeg jng lqr pango png x11 xml zlib
```